# Jetpack Compose Playground

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

is there any online playground for jetpack compose? where I can test and learn jetpack compose. Like https://play.kotlinlang.org

Android studio is not lite. It takes time for setting up projects. Every little practice takes lots of time. If there is an online playground, it will be very help full. Thanks.

Comment: No there is not

Comment: Maybe there is no exact playground as kotlinglang.org has but you can use search Codelabs tutorials and learn from those. Codelabs has tutorials about many subjects for Jetpack Compose

Comment: On the other hand, Android Studio offers you (1) a preview pane for Jetpack Compose where you can preview composables, (2) documentation and code assist for builtin composables and modifiers, (3) option to check the definitions of built-in composables (just from that you can learn a lot how Compose works). So, imo, it is worth installing studio that single time to then reap all those benefits. It will also make following tutorials easier.

Answer (score 0):

While there is no online playground where you can try it in a web browser, there is playground projects that you can clone from Github.

Here's one:
https://github.com/hitherejoe/ComposeAcademy-Playground

You can clone the project, open it and start experimenting with the [`@Preview` annotation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/tooling#preview) or by extending the existing samples.